# A finitely generated ideal of an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, integral-domain

Let $D$ be an integral domain and $Q(D)$ be the ring of fractions
of $D$. If $I$ is an ideal of $D$ with the property that if for **all** ideals $J\not=0$ of $D$ such that $J\subseteq I$, there exists a
subset $A_J$ of $Q(D)$ such that $A_JJ=I$. My professor said that
$I$ must be a finitely generated ideal of $D$, but I could not prove that. Why is $I$ finitely generated ideal of $D$?

Comment: If $I\ne 0$ and $J=0$ I can't see how to find such a subset.

Answer (score 0):

As you state this, you could have $J=I$, $A_J=\{1\}$ and $I$
a non-finitely generated ideal. So, the conclusion doesn't follow.

What is the case is that if $AI=D$ for some fractional ideal $A$, then $I$
is finitely generated.

Comment: I am so sorry. It was corrected.